# Is digit, aplha or math symbol

Tags: python

I have a logger that listens to sequences such as equations, but I need to remove all the keypresses like "L_control" or "shift", what I do is get the ascii number and then use chr(event.Ascii) but it comes back with the ctrl and shift presses as a space.

I'm currently using this to remove all the characters I don't want but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas of improvements?

```
def removeChars(l):
    acceptedChars = ["[", "]", "+", "-", "/", "*", "^", "*", "(", ")"]
    newL = ""
    for x in range(0, len(l)):
        if l[x].isalpha() or l[x] in acceptedChars or l[x].isdigit():
            newL = newL + l[x]
    return newL
```

---

Edit:

I am using `pyHook` to get the key event and using `event.Ascii` to get the Ascii value then using `chr(event.Ascii)` to get the character

Comment: How are you getting this `l` object? You shouldn't be getting raw keypresses.

Comment: What is the output? And `l` is not defined. So whats the input? Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: l is a parameter in the method/function and l is returned, Ill fix it up, l is a string, Im using pyHook and pythoncom to do it, and when there is a keypress `onKeyEvent(event)` is called, then you call `event.Ascii` to get the ascii value, then you can use `chr(event.Ascii)` to get the character

Comment: http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/doc/pyhook/public/pyHook.HookManager.KeyboardEvent-class.html#Ascii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import string
acceptedChars = set(string.printable)
newL = ''.join([ x for x in l if x in acceptedChars])
```

---

Edit:

You can use anything in `set()` to match to for example to just get digits, letters, and selected symbols:

```
acceptedChars = set(string.digits + "[]()+-/*^=!<>" + string.letters)
newL = ''.join([ x for x in l if x in acceptedChars])
```

Comment: What about the digits and alpha characters? And I want to remove things like space, fullstops etc

Comment: You could use any set for acceptedChars, like set( string.printable) - set(string.whitespace) or set(string.ascii_letters) + set(string.digits) + set(string.punctuation)

Comment: I think a regex would be faster `new_string=re.sub("[^\[\]+-*/^a-zA-Z0-9]","",old_string)`